# How to integrate Fabric8 with Eclipse?

Tags: java, osgi, eclipse-kepler, fabric8

I'm using *fabric8-karaf-1.1.0.CR5* in a stand-alone installation and it works fine there.

Now I wanted to embedd it into *Eclipse Kepler SR2*.

I basically followed [Integrating Felix with Eclipse](https://felix.apache.org/site/integrating-felix-with-eclipse.html). But, instead of just adding `bin/felix.jar` to the project's build path as in *Figure 8* I added all jars of `lib` and its sub-directories `bin` and `endorsed` (after *a lot* of errors were thrown at me by just adding `lib/karaf.jar`).

There are still three issues:

1. The following is printed to System.err:

   ```
   Jul 28, 2014 12:12:24 AM org.apache.karaf.main.SimpleFileLock lock
   Information: locking
   ```

   What does this error(?) message try to inform me of? That a file named `lock` is created in the project's root directory? Thank you, but why?
2. The following is printed to System.err:

   ```
   Error in initialization script: \shell.init.script
   (The system cannot find the file specified)
   ```

   The parenthesized is the Windows version of a FileNotFoundException's detail message. There exists an `etc\shell.init.script` and for the sake of the directory not mentioned I copied it to the project's root folder, to no avail.
3. I had to comment the following bundles in `etc\config.properties`:

   ```
   #org/apache/sshd/sshd-core/0.9.0/sshd-core-0.9.0.jar=30
   #org/apache/karaf/shell/org.apache.karaf.shell.ssh/2.3.0.redhat-610379/org.apache.karaf.shell.ssh-2.3.0.redhat-610379.jar=30
   #io/fabric8/fabric-zookeeper/1.1.0.CR5/fabric-zookeeper-1.1.0.CR5.jar=39
   #io/fabric8/fabric-api/1.1.0.CR5/fabric-api-1.1.0.CR5.jar=40
   #io/fabric8/fabric-agent/1.1.0.CR5/fabric-agent-1.1.0.CR5.jar=40
   #io/fabric8/fabric-core/1.1.0.CR5/fabric-core-1.1.0.CR5.jar=45
   #io/fabric8/fabric-boot-commands/1.1.0.CR5/fabric-boot-commands-1.1.0.CR5.jar=45
   #io/fabric8/fabric-commands/1.1.0.CR5/fabric-commands-1.1.0.CR5.jar=50
   #io/fabric8/fabric-configadmin/1.1.0.CR5/fabric-configadmin-1.1.0.CR5.jar=50
   ```

   ... to get rid off errors of the form:

   ```
   ERROR: Bundle <Bundle-SymbolicName> [<ID>]
   Error starting mvn:<bundle-path> (org.osgi.framework.BundleException:
   Unresolved constraint in bundle <Bundle-SymbolicName>:
   Unable to resolve <ID>.0: missing requirement [<ID>.0] osgi.wiring.package;
   (&(osgi.wiring.package=<Other Bundle-SymbolicName>)(<versions>))))
   ```

   ... but with these bundles disabled Fabric8 shuts down immediately.

   It's right, the few missing  bundles I have checked aren't in my local .m2 repository. But Maven works well with all other projects, in and out of Eclipse. Go on Fabric8, download them!

What am I missing?

Comment: What is your purpose of integrating felix with Eclipse?

Comment: @Claus Ibsen
Because it's called **I**DE? ;-) I was attracted by the sentence >_Then, it is possible to use Eclipse debugging facilities to debug bundles._< But, however, I can live with `KARAF_DEBUG=true` and remote debugging from within Eclipse.